# I want to do different actions on clicking different buttons, the code i have written is not working?

Tags: html, django

**Template**

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="col"><p>Firstname: {{i.fname}}</p></div>
          <div class="col"><p>Lastname: {{i.lname}}</p></div>
          <div class="col"><p>Email: {{i.email}}</p></div>
          <div class="col"><p>City: {{i.city}}</p></div>
          <div class="col"><p>Pin: {{i.pin}}</p></div>
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input type="hidden" name="Approve" value="{{ i.fname }}">
          <input class="btn btn-success mx-2" type="submit" value="Approve">
          <input type="hidden" name="Reject" value="{{ i.id }}">
          <input class="btn btn-danger mx-2" type="submit" value="Reject">
      </form>
```

**Views.py**

```
def adminp(request):
    if 'Reject' in request.POST and request.method=="POST":
        print("Went into reject")
        p=booking.objects.filter(id=request.POST.get('Reject','')).delete()
    elif 'Approve' in request.POST and request.POST.method=="POST":
        print("went into approve")
    x=booking.objects.all()
    print(x)
    params={'pro': x}
    return render(request,'dbms/adminpanel.html',params)
```

**How do i resolve the above code?
In views.py always the request goes in reject itself also onclicking approve ,help please.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it like this:

First update the form's submit button to have a `name="foobar"` attribute:

```
  <form action="" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="col"><p>Firstname: {{i.fname}}</p></div>
      <div class="col"><p>Lastname: {{i.lname}}</p></div>
      <div class="col"><p>Email: {{i.email}}</p></div>
      <div class="col"><p>City: {{i.city}}</p></div>
      <div class="col"><p>Pin: {{i.pin}}</p></div>
      <input class="btn btn-success mx-2" name="form_approved" type="submit" value="Approve">
      <input type="hidden" name="object_id" value="{{ i.id }}">
      <input class="btn btn-danger mx-2" name="form_rejected" type="submit" value="Reject">  // Added attribute name="form_rejected"
  </form>
```

Then check if `foobar` exists in the `request.POST`:

```
 # View
 def adminp(request):
    if 'form_rejected' in request.POST and request.method=="POST":
        print("Went into reject")
        p=booking.objects.filter(id=request.POST.get('object_id','')).delete()
```